# Merging two tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

table1:

```
| id            | int(11)      
| name          | varchar(255) 
| type          | varchar(255) 
| property1     | varchar(255) 
| property2     | varchar(255) 
| property3     | varchar(255)
```

table2:

```
| id            | int(11)      
| name          | varchar(255) 
| type_level    | varchar(255) 
| property11    | varchar(255) 
| property12    | varchar(255) 
....
| property33    | varchar(255)
```

These tables basically represent the same entity. table1 is like a short list of properties, table2 contains more information.

The `name` property has the same value in both tables for any given entity, **not** the ID; `type` and `type_level` contain the same value but are unfortunately just named differently.

I just started this project and I think this situation isn't very good, I'd like to merge the tables.

I'd like to merge the tables to create this table:

table_merged

```
| id            | int(11)      
| name          | varchar(255) 
| type          | varchar(255) 
| property1     | varchar(255) 
| property2     | varchar(255) 
| property3     | varchar(255) 
| property11    | varchar(255) 
| property12    | varchar(255) 
| property13    | varchar(255) 
....
| property33    | varchar(255)
```

The resulting table should confer a unique ID to every row, and the rows with the same `name` should be joined in one single row....

I hope I explained it well enough. How can I accomplish this? I tried `INNER JOIN` and `UNION` but so far not in the correct way.

Comment: won't `INSERT INTO table_merged (...) values ( select ... from table1 1inner join table 2 b on a.name=b.name` do?

Comment: can you not use `table2` alone dropping `table1`, as you mention `table2` has all information of `table1` ?

Comment: @vkp no, table1 has property1, property2 and property3 which need to go into the merged table and table2 doesn't have those :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there are no duplicate names in either table and that they match, you can do what you want with a `join`:

```
create table table_merged as
    select (@rn := @rn + 1) as id, t1.name, t1.type,
           t1.property1, t1.property2, t1.property3,
           t2.property11, t2.property12, t2.property13, . . .
    from table1 t1 left join
         table2 t2
         on t1.name = t2.name and t1.type = t2.type_name cross join
         (select @rn := 0) params;
```

This version adds yet another new id for the merged table.

Comment: booah I would never have been able to come up with smth like this. Care sharing what `(@rn := @rn + 1)` and `(select @rn := 0)` are doing?

Comment: @faboolous . . . That expression is using variables to assign a new sequential id.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new table, assign `AUTO INCREMENT` to the id and just insert select:

```
 insert into table_merged (name,property1,....
 values(select a.name, a.property1, a.property2, a.property3, b.property11...
 from table1 a left join table2 b on a.name = b.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems full join is needed here in general case - rows may be only  in table1, or only in table2, or in both .  Common FULL JOIN workaround for mysql is

```
SELECT t1.name,t1.type, t1.property1, ... , t2.proerty11, ...
FROM table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON (t1.name = t2.name and t1.type = t2.type_name )
UNION 
SELECT t1.name,t1.type, t1.property1, ... , t2.proerty11, ...
FROM table2 t2 
LEFT JOIN table1 t1 ON (t1.name = t2.name and t1.type = t2.type_name )
```